# Ajax doesn't execute if condition statements in the controller's function in codeigniter 4,

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter-4

I'm just beginning to learn jQuery and Ajax along with Codeigniter 4 framework, I have encountered this problem when trying to update some columns in database with Ajax, it happened that Ajax works totally fine and update the data on database through the update function but if condition statement not touched by Ajax through the url, what could a problem?

my jQuery/Ajax

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.downloadRep').on('click', function() {
    $('#DownloadRep').modal('show');

    $tr = $(this).closest('tr');

    var data = $tr.children("td").map(function() {
      return $(this).text();
    }).get();

    $('#data_id').val(data[0]);

  });


  $(document).on('click', '#submitForm', function() {

    if ($.trim($('.name').val()).length == 0) {
      error_name = 'Enter full name';

      $('#error_name').text(error_name);
    } else {
      error_name = '';
      $('#error_name').text(error_name);
    }

    if ($.trim($('.phone').val()).length == 0) {
      error_phone = 'Enter Phone Number';

      $('#error_phone').text(error_phone);
    } else {
      error_phone = '';
      $('#error_phone').text(error_phone);
    }

    if ($.trim($('.dateof').val()).length == 0) {
      error_date = 'Enter the date';

      $('#error_date').text(error_date);
    } else {
      error_date = '';
      $('#error_date').text(error_date);
    }

    if (error_name != '' || error_phone != '' || error_date != '') {
      return false;
    } else {

      var data = {
        'data_id': $('.data_id').val(),
        'name': $('.name').val(),
        'phone': $('.phone').val(),
        'dateof': $('.dateof').val()
      }

      $.ajax({

        method: "POST",
        url: "<?=base_url('/admin/downloadrep');?>",
        data: data,
        success: function(response) {
          location.reload();
          $('#DownloadRep').modal('hide');
          $('#DownloadRep').find('input').val('');
        }

      });


    }
  });
});
```

This is controller method,

```php
public function downloadrep(){
  $dataId=$this->request->getPost('data_id');
  $data = [
    'name_of_valuer'=>$this->request->getPost('name'), 
    'phone'=>$this->request->getPost('phone'),
    'date_report'=>$this->request->getPost('dateof') 
  ];
  $downloadrep= new \App\Models\ValuerReq(); 
  $dataupdatetodownload= $downloadrep->update($dataId,$data);
  if(!$dataupdatetodownload) {     
    return redirect()->back()->with('fail', 'Not Updated');
  } else {
   return redirect()->to('/admin/valuersrequesttoadminsub')->with('success', 'Download Started'); 
  }
}
```

Comment: Move the id from the submit button to the form tag and do`$(document).on('submit', '#submitForm', function(e) { e.preventDefault(); /* rest of your code */ ... });`

Comment: Also get the values once. No need to fist get the values, test them and then get them again

Answer (score 0):

Your AJAX response that should be JSON but in your php code it is using redirect() which is not suitable for the AJAX response but it should be like

```
if (!$dataupdatetodownload) {     
    return $this->response->setJSON(['status' => 'fail', 'message' => 'Not Updated']);
} else {
    return $this->response->setJSON(['status' => 'success', 'message' => 'Download Started']);
}
```

and in your AJAX response something like this

```
success: function(response){
    if(response.status === 'success') {
        // Handle success scenario
    } else {
        // Handle failure scenario
    }
}
```